Expected value of max{X,Y} when (X,Y) is bivariate normal
Asking an already asked question but I am stuck in my proof. I know that if $corr(X,Y)=\rho$, $E[\max(X,Y)] = \sqrt{\left(\frac{1-\rho}{\pi}\right)}$.
My process:
$$E[\max(X, Y)] = E[X|X-Y>0].\Pr(X-Y>0) + E[Y|Y-X>0].\Pr(Y-X>0) $$
$$E[\max(X, Y)] = 2E[X|X-Y>0]\frac{1}{2} = E[X|X-Y>0]$$
Now I know that a normally distributed random variable with mean $0$ has the following conditional expectation:
$$E[Z|Z>0] = \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{(2\pi)}}$$
With $Z=X-Y$, $V(Z)=2(1-\rho)$ so:
$$E[Z|Z>0] = \sqrt{\left(\frac{1-\rho}{\pi}\right)}$$
Now what I don't understand is that it seems that $E[\max(X,Y)] = E[Z|Z>0]$, but how could it be knowing that $corr(X,Z) = 1/2$ ? How can I get from $E[Z|Z>0]$ to $E[X|Z>0]$ ? Thanks

Note that $\max(X,Y) = Y + \max(X-Y,0)$, the latter term being constantly zero, unless $Z = X-Y > 0$, hence $\max(X-Y,0) \sim Z|Z>0$. Finally, given that $Y$ has zero mean, one ends up with
$$
\Bbb{E}[\max(X,Y)] = \Bbb{E}[Y] + \Bbb{E}[\max(X-Y,0)] = \Bbb{E}[Z|Z>0]
$$
by linearity.
